# Where i can find .ideavimrc file of ideavim 0.41 on windows 7?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ideavim

I use android studio on Windows 7 and it installed IdeaVim, i used `:map jj <Esc>` (i know it's a mistake), after that i used `:map jj` in order to disable it and it became `<Nop>`. But when i came back to command mode, i can't use <kbd>j</kbd> to go down anymore. I tried `unmap`, `mapclear`,.. but it's not work.

So now i want to find .ideavimrc file to remove that mapping (i am a newbie about vim, so detail please :D )

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is in your home directory (`C:\Users\your_username`)

Comment: is it hide? i can't see it https://i.imgur.com/evRUNU4.png

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a problem with this too. I found out it was because I hadn't created the file. I am on Windows 7 and am using Android Studio.

1. Go to C:/Users/YourUserName/.ideavimrc.
2. If .ideavimrc doesn't exist, you need to create it.
3. Add the code you want - such as 
       `:set number`

[Windows 7 .ideavimrc settings for IdeaVim](http://www.derekkier.com/2015/10/20/android-studio-ideavim-configuration-for-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks so much :D, just make it

Comment: Note: On windows 10, I found that I was not able to just rename a txt file to .ideavimrc. Instead I had to create a file from the cmd line.

Comment: Under the current plugin implementation, there is a small blue-green "V" icon in the bottom right corner.  Clicking it pops up a small menu for the plugin, including an option for opening `.ideavimrc` in an editor tab.  I do not know whether the file must already exist; I only discovered the icon after I'd already created the file.  I'm using version 0.56 of the plugin but I don't know when this would have been added.

Comment: @TiStrga Thanks.  I haven't had the file created, and clicking that icon gave ma an option to Create one.  After clicking it it created it in the directory specified above

Answer (score 3):

I've suffered the same problem.

My Env: Windows 8, Android Studio 1.5.1, IdeaVim 0.41

- C:\Users\_ideavimrc
- C:\Users\.ideavimrc

Both files are working properly.

- :set number
- set number

Both cases are working properly.

Comment: in C:\Users ? or C:\Users\$username\ ?

Comment: This worked on Windows 10 in 2023.