# IdeaVIM: cannot copy and paste multi time

Tags: intellij-idea, copy-paste, ideavim

I have this scenario. For example, I have 3 lines of text with following content:

```
first_line
second_line
third_line
```

I want to copy text `first_line` to replace `second_line` and `third_line`. So after copy and replace, new content should be:

```
first_line
first_line
first_line
```

I do by: press <kbd>viw</kbd> for selecting `first_line` text. Then go to second line, press <kbd>vi</kbd> for selecting `second_line` text, then press <kbd>p</kbd> for replacing text.

I repeat again by go to third line. But at this time, text `second_line` is saved to clipboard **automatically** (I don't copy it). so when I replace `third_line` text, new text will be `second_line`. So new content will be:

```
first_line
first_line
second_line
```

This behavior annoys me so much. It makes me cannot copy one content to many places. How can I fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that at least part of your problem is related to the register being used to store the copied text, so a possible solution is to customize such behavior for IdeaVIM, as indicated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928635/606826), you can edit your ~/.ideavimrc file and add the following two lines, create that file if it does not exists:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

I had to restart the IDE for this changes to take effect.

Now I you should be able to paste multiple lines using `"+p` or `"*p` see this [article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard) for more details.